# iOS Security.framework arm64 architecture issue

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, arm64, security.framework

I am trying to compile an app on an iPhone 6 device under iOS 11.4.

This app uses a framework of my own compiled for architectures armv7 and arm64 (confirmed with lipo -info) and targetted for iOS8+.

In this framework, I use *kSecImportExportPassphrase*, *SecPKCS12Import* and *kSecImportItemIdentity* from the Security.framework of iOS.

When I compile in Xcode 10.2, I get this error:

[image: Xcode 10.2 error]

If someone get an idea of what is going on?

It is like the Security.framework is not compiled for arm64 which is quite impossible.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

1. Set Architectures to armv7 armv7s, `Build Active Architecture Only` to NO, for every target in the project, including every one in Pods:

`ARCHS = armv7 armv7s`

`VALID_ARCHS = armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64`

2. Clean project, shutdown Xcode, then find your application in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` and move it trash then empty it.

Comment: Hello Allen,
Thanks for your response.

I tried your solutions. It still not working but this time I have the same error message but for armv7 architecture.

Comment: Since Apple now demands support for 64 bit for all deployments, lets try something else. Get rid of everything but ```arm64``` in ```ARCHS``` and ```VALID_ARCHS```. And set ```Build Active Architecture Only``` to ```YES```.

Comment: Same issue as before.

I have set to `arm64` in `ARCHS` and `VALID_ARCHS` and set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `YES` for my framework and my app.

Comment: I have one more idea: check to location of the framework from "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". Verify that it is pointing to the SDK version of the framework, and not somewhere else.